# React useState overwriting Array?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-hooks

I have an array, set up with useState in React. I would like to add an element to it, given that it doesn't contain the element yet.

The syntax should be fine, but React always overwrites the array, so the array always contains just one element. Does anyone have an idea why?

```
const isInArray = (arr: any, elCompare:any) => {    
    return  arr.some((el:any) => {
      return el.keyword_uid === elCompare.srcElement.__data__.data.uid
    }) ? [...arr]
    : [...arr, {keyword_uid: elCompare.srcElement.__data__.data.uid, keyword_name: elCompare.srcElement.__data__.data.name}]
  }

  const buttonClicked =(d:any) => {
    setFilterArray(isInArray(dictFilterArray, d))
  }
```

Comment: A useful Information maybe: After I save the the changes it works normally. When I refresh the page it is broken again.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior for setting state in React. Whatever you pass into your setState functions will be used as the new state.

If you want to add onto an array type state, you will have to make a copy of the current state, push some new data inside it, and then pass the copy into your setState function.

Try this:

```
  const buttonClicked =(d:any) => {
    setFilterArray(...filterArray, isInArray(dictFilterArray, d))
  }
```

Comment: Ah yes! But I am doing that, I just gave it its own function:
```? [...arr]
    : [...arr, {keyword_uid: elCompare.srcElement.__data__.data.uid, keyword_name: elCompare.srcElement.__data__.data.name}]
  }```

Comment: I assumed that ```dictFilterArray``` wasn't state by its name. Then the condition is wrong. When your ```some``` is _true_ you are defaulting to your current state right now. You should try inverting it.